# android multiple selection with following ui

Tags: android

[image]

A client has asked me to create a ui .
I have a recycler view and inside it, a  spinner is there with multiple selection 
and done button after selection of multiple selection.if I select multiple values in spinner then the hint (default value) will be 1+more and if no value is selected then default value should be "Select a value". please provide a appropriate answer for the following ui . or any other way to do it.

Comment: Just create a recycler view with an item layout that contains a spinner...

Comment: Share your code what you have tried to achieve. We can't resolve there is no code to try.

Comment: spinner don't have any option to select multiple item .  when  I add checkbox in spinner that will take the focus and click will not work in spinner

Comment: @ Mohamed Mohaideen AH You just tell me how you will achieve this .

Answer (score 0):

If you talk about multiple choice spinner then refer below code

**SimpleActivity.java**

```
public class SampleActivity extends AppCompatActivity{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.simple_activity);

        MultiSelectorSpinnerObjects multiSelectorSpinnerObjects = (MultiSelectorSpinnerObjects) findViewById(R.id.multispinner);

        // You can use string array also
        /*-String[] stringArr = new String[]{"One", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five", "Six", "Seven", "Eight", "Nine", "Ten"};
        multiSelectorSpinnerObjects.setItems(stringArr);*/


        ArrayList<String> stringList = new ArrayList<>();
        stringList.add("One"); stringList.add("Two"); stringList.add("Three"); stringList.add("Four");
        stringList.add("Five"); stringList.add("Six"); stringList.add("Seven"); stringList.add("Eight");
        stringList.add("Nine"); stringList.add("Ten");

        multiSelectorSpinnerObjects.setItems(stringList);
    }
}
```

**MultiSelectorSpinnerObjects.java**

```
public class MultiSelectorSpinnerObjects extends Spinner implements
        OnMultiChoiceClickListener {

    private static final String TAG = "MultiSelectorSpinnerObjects";
    String[] _items = null;
    boolean[] mSelection = null;
    boolean[] mSelectionAtStart = null;
    String _itemsAtStart = null;

    private ArrayAdapter<String> simple_adapter;

    public MultiSelectorSpinnerObjects(Context context) {
        super(context);

        simple_adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(context, R.layout.spinner_item);
        super.setAdapter(simple_adapter);
    }

    public MultiSelectorSpinnerObjects(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);

        simple_adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(context, R.layout.spinner_item);
        super.setAdapter(simple_adapter);
    }

    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which, boolean isChecked) {
        if (mSelection != null && which < mSelection.length) {
            mSelection[which] = isChecked;
            simple_adapter.clear();
            simple_adapter.add(buildSelectedItemString());
        } else {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                    "Argument 'which' is out of bounds.");
        }
    }

    @SuppressLint("ClickableViewAccessibility")
    @Override
    public boolean performClick() {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext());
        builder.setMultiChoiceItems(_items, mSelection, this);
        _itemsAtStart = getSelectedItemsAsString();
        builder.setPositiveButton("Submit", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                System.arraycopy(mSelection, 0, mSelectionAtStart, 0, mSelection.length);
            }
        });
        builder.setNegativeButton(getResources().getString(R.string.cancel), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                simple_adapter.clear();
                simple_adapter.add(_itemsAtStart);
                System.arraycopy(mSelectionAtStart, 0, mSelection, 0, mSelectionAtStart.length);
            }
        });
        builder.show();
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void setAdapter(SpinnerAdapter adapter) {
        throw new RuntimeException(
                "setAdapter is not supported by MultiSelectSpinner.");
    }

    public void setItems(String[] items) {
        _items = items;
        int _itemsSize = _items.length;
        mSelection = new boolean[_itemsSize];
        mSelectionAtStart = new boolean[_itemsSize];
        simple_adapter.clear();
        simple_adapter.add(_items[0]);
        Arrays.fill(mSelection, false);
        mSelection[0] = true;
        mSelectionAtStart[0] = true;
    }

    public void setItems(List<String> items) {
        _items = items.toArray(new String[items.size()]);
        int _itemsSize = _items.length;
        mSelection = new boolean[_itemsSize];
        mSelectionAtStart = new boolean[_itemsSize];
        simple_adapter.clear();
        for (int i = 0; i < _itemsSize; i++) {
            simple_adapter.add(_items[i]);
        }
        Arrays.fill(mSelection, false);
        mSelection[0] = true;
    }

    public void setSelection(String[] selection) {
        int _itemsSize = _items.length;
        for (String cell : selection) {
            for (int j = 0; j < _itemsSize; ++j) {
                if (_items[j].equals(cell)) {
                    mSelection[j] = true;
                    mSelectionAtStart[j] = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void setSelection(List<String> selection) {
        int selectionSize = mSelection.length;
        for (int i = 0; i < selectionSize; i++) {
            mSelection[i] = false;
            mSelectionAtStart[i] = false;
        }
        int _itemsSize = _items.length;
        for (String sel : selection) {
            for (int j = 0; j < _itemsSize; ++j) {
                if (_items[j].equals(sel)) {
                    mSelection[j] = true;
                    mSelectionAtStart[j] = true;
                }
            }
        }
        simple_adapter.clear();
        simple_adapter.add(buildSelectedItemString());
    }

    public void setSelection(int index) {
        int selectionSize = mSelection.length;
        for (int i = 0; i < selectionSize; i++) {
            mSelection[i] = false;
            mSelectionAtStart[i] = false;
        }
        if (index >= 0 && index < selectionSize) {
            mSelection[index] = true;
            mSelectionAtStart[index] = true;
        } else {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Index " + index
                                               + " is out of bounds.");
        }
        simple_adapter.clear();
        simple_adapter.add(buildSelectedItemString());
    }

    public void setSelection(int[] selectedIndices) {
        int selectionSize = mSelection.length;
        for (int i = 0; i < selectionSize; i++) {
            mSelection[i] = false;
            mSelectionAtStart[i] = false;
        }
        for (int index : selectedIndices) {
            if (index >= 0 && index < selectionSize) {
                mSelection[index] = true;
                mSelectionAtStart[index] = true;
            } else {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Index " + index
                                                   + " is out of bounds.");
            }
        }
        simple_adapter.clear();
        simple_adapter.add(buildSelectedItemString());
    }

    public List<String> getSelectedStrings() {
        List<String> selection = new LinkedList<>();
        int _itemsSize = _items.length;
        for (int i = 0; i < _itemsSize; ++i) {
            if (mSelection[i]) {
                selection.add(_items[i]);
            }
        }
        return selection;
    }

    public List<Integer> getSelectedIndices() {
        List<Integer> selection = new LinkedList<>();
        int _itemsSize = _items.length;
        for (int i = 0; i < _itemsSize; ++i) {
            if (mSelection[i]) {
                selection.add(i);
            }
        }
        return selection;
    }

    private String buildSelectedItemString() {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        boolean foundOne = false;
        int _itemsSize = _items.length;
        for (int i = 0; i < _itemsSize; ++i) {
            if (mSelection[i]) {
                if (foundOne) {
                    sb.append(", ");
                }
                foundOne = true;

                sb.append(_items[i]);

            }
        }
        if (sb.length() == 0) {
            sb.append("Select Tag");
            return sb.toString();
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }

    public String getSelectedItemsAsString() {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        boolean foundOne = false;
        int _itemsSize = _items.length;
        for (int i = 0; i < _itemsSize; ++i) {
            if (mSelection[i]) {
                if (foundOne) {
                    sb.append(", ");
                }
                foundOne = true;
                sb.append(_items[i]);
            }
        }
        if (sb.length() == 0) {
            sb.append("Select Tag");
            return sb.toString();
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }

    public String getSelectedItemsAsId() {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        boolean foundOne = false;
        int _itemsSize = _items.length;
        for (int i = 0; i < _itemsSize; ++i) {
            if (mSelection[i]) {
                if (foundOne) {
                    sb.append(",");
                }
            }
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }

}
```

**spinner_item.xml**

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:id="@+id/text1"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:textSize="15sp"
          android:maxLines="1"
          android:ellipsize="end"
          android:paddingLeft="4dip"
          android:gravity="center_vertical"
          android:textColor="#929292"/>
```

**simple_activity.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.taxsmart.behaviorobservation.component.MultiSelectorSpinnerObjects
        android:id="@+id/multispinner"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp">

    </com.taxsmart.behaviorobservation.component.MultiSelectorSpinnerObjects>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Hope this will work for you.

Comment: I am appreciating   your work but i don't want a dialog . I need a dropdown with same options.